# Including an svg element in my html breaks jquery ui

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am having a very weird issue that I have no idea whatsoever how to debug.
I have a html file with a div that has the jquery UI draggable enabled:

```
$(function() {
    $(".ideanode").draggable({ containment: "parent" });
});
```

this is working fine and dandy until I include this in my html:

```
<svg id="connectors" height="100%" width="100%">
                <defs>
                    <marker id="markerArrow" markerWidth="13" markerHeight="13" refX="2" refY="6"
                           orient="auto">
                        <path d="M2,2 L2,11 L10,6 L2,2" />
                    </marker>
                </defs>

                <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="100" class="arrow" />
              </svg>
```

This just completely removes the draggable functionality of my div and I can't even begin to understand why. I will link to a full example as well.
https://codepen.io/ricodon1000/pen/XWmqxeB
If any additional information is needed please ask, I'm still learning how to post really good questions here. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a global style

```
svg{
  background:red;
  opacity:.5;
}
```

and you will see the SVG is covering the whole screen, thus blocking every element underneath

Comment: oh okay makes sense, how could I work around this? In other words how can I make the SVG only be the size of the actual arrow?

Comment: nvm, figured it out, I simply set the pointer-events to none, thank you!